# Вывод нескольких SELECT-ов в одну таблицу

Tags: sql, postgresql, запрос-в-запросе

### Postgresql 9.2

Нужно все эти запросы ниже вывести в одну таблицу (собираю статистику)

```
SELECT "customer"."id", "customer"."email", "customer"."unsubscribed_types"
FROM
    "customer"
WHERE
    "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'daily_weekdays'
    OR "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'daily_weekends'
    OR "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'weekly_free'
    OR "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'weekly_best_weekly'
    OR "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'special_partner'
    OR "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'bonus_activation'
LIMIT 100;
```

---

```
SELECT
    "customer".email,
    "customer".id,
    "customer".unsubscribed_types
FROM
    "customer"
WHERE
    "customer".unsubscribed_types ISNULL
OR "customer".unsubscribed_types = '' 
LIMIT 100;
```

---

```
SELECT
    "customer".email,
    "customer".id,
    "customer".unsubscribed_types
FROM
    "customer"
WHERE
    "customer".unsubscribed_types = 'daily_weekdays'
    AND "customer".unsubscribed_types = 'daily_weekends'
    AND "customer".unsubscribed_types = 'weekly_free'
    AND "customer".unsubscribed_types = 'weekly_best_weekly'
    AND "customer".unsubscribed_types = 'special_partner'
    AND "customer".unsubscribed_types = 'bonus_activation';
    LIMIT 100;
```

---

```
SELECT
    "customer".id,
    "customer".email,
    "customer".unsubscribed_types
FROM
    "customer"
WHERE
    unsubscribed_types = 'daily_weekdays';
LIMIT 100;
```

Прошу заметить мне не объеденить а вывести статистику(например)

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Запрос 1 | Сколько нашел людей из 1-го селекта|
|-----------------------------------------------|
| Запрос 2 | Сколько нашел людей из 2-го селекта|
|-----------------------------------------------|
| Запрос 3 | Сколько нашел людей из 3-го селекта|
|-----------------------------------------------|
| Запрос 4 | Сколько нашел людей из 4-го селекта|
-------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как решил проблему

```
SELECT
"request_1" AS "Запрос 1",
"request_2" AS "Запрос 2",
"request_3" AS "Запрос 3",
"request_4" AS "Запрос 4"
FROM
(
    -- Исполняем запрос 1
    SELECT count("customer"."id")
    FROM "customer"
    WHERE
        "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'daily_weekdays'
        OR "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'daily_weekends'
        OR "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'weekly_free'
        OR "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'weekly_best_weekly'
        OR "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'special_partner'
        OR "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'bonus_activation'
) AS "request_1",

(
    -- Исполняем запрос 2
    SELECT count("customer"."id")
    FROM "customer"
    WHERE
        "customer"."unsubscribed_types" ISNULL
        OR "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = '{}'
) AS "request_2",


(
    -- Исполняем запрос 3
    SELECT count("customer"."id")
    FROM "customer"
    WHERE
        "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'daily_weekdays'
        AND "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'daily_weekends'
        AND "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'weekly_free'
        AND "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'weekly_best_weekly'
        AND "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'special_partner'
        AND "customer"."unsubscribed_types" = 'bonus_activation'
) AS "request_3",

(
    -- Исполняем запрос 4
    SELECT count("customer"."id")
    FROM "customer"
    WHERE "unsubscribed_types" = 'daily_weekdays'
) AS "request_4",
;
```

Answer (score 3):

можно воспользоваться объединением запросов ([*union*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28SQL%29)):

```
select "запрос 1", count(*)
from ... where ...
union
select "запрос 2", count(*)
from ... where ...
union
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Предложу такой вариант:
Написать процедуру, в которой:
1) Будет создаваться таблица, определяющая Вашу результирующую таблицу
2) Делать выборки исходной таблицы
3) Проходится по каждой выборки и вставлять данные в таблицу, созданную в 1 пункте